# Pointers based code giving Segmentation fault in CodeBlocks

Tags: c, pointers, codeblocks

This is my code. I keep getting a segmentation fault at the end of code. All the things running fine but the segmentation fault comes at the end.

I am trying to prepare checkers game and the first step is to initialize each piece with a symbol. This code tries to do the same.

CodeBlocks version : 13.12
Windows 7

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define boardheight 8
#define boardwidth 8
struct Player_symbols{
    char symbol;
    char king_symbol;
};

struct Checker_piece{
    char king;
    int on_board;
    int num_moves;
    int player;
    struct Player_symbols* symbols;
};

int pieces_count[2] = {12,12};
struct Checker_piece* player_1_pieces;
struct Checker_piece* player_2_pieces;

void initialize_player_pieces(struct Checker_piece* player_pieces, struct Player_symbols* player_symbols, int player_num);
void initialize_board(struct Checker_piece* checker_board[boardheight][boardwidth],struct Checker_piece* player1,struct Checker_piece* player2);
void print_board(struct Checker_piece* checker_board[boardheight][boardwidth]);
int move_piece(struct Checker_piece* checker_board[boardheight][boardwidth], int x,int y,int player);
void continue_jumping(struct Checker_piece* checker_board[boardheight][boardwidth],int* y,int* x,int player);
int generate_destination(int x, int *dest_x, int *dest_y, int *dest_y_jump,int dest_y2,int dest_y2_jump,int move_flags,int player);

int main()
{

    struct Checker_piece* checker_board[boardheight][boardwidth];
    struct Checker_piece* dummy;
    struct Player_symbols* dummy_symbol;
    //declare and initialize the Checker_piece structures by allocating memory dynamically using a dummy structure to determine its size
    player_1_pieces = malloc(12*sizeof dummy);
    player_2_pieces = malloc(12*sizeof dummy);
    struct Player_symbols *player_1_symbols,*player_2_symbols;

    player_1_symbols = malloc(sizeof dummy_symbol);
    player_2_symbols = malloc(sizeof dummy_symbol);

    //initialize the player symbols
    player_1_symbols->symbol = 'o';
    player_1_symbols->king_symbol = 'O';
    player_2_symbols->symbol = 'x';
    player_2_symbols->king_symbol = 'X';

    initialize_player_pieces(player_1_pieces,player_1_symbols,1);
    initialize_player_pieces(player_2_pieces,player_2_symbols,2);

    printf("Done");
    return 0;
}

void initialize_player_pieces(struct Checker_piece* player_pieces, struct Player_symbols* player_symbols, int player_num){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<12; i++, player_pieces++ ) {
        player_pieces->king='N';
        player_pieces->num_moves=0;
        player_pieces->on_board=1;
        player_pieces->player=player_num;
        player_pieces->symbols= player_symbols;
    }
}
```

Comment: `sizeof dummy_symbol` and `sizeof dummy` is not what you think it is.

Comment: I would say that it has nothing to do with Codeblocks. My guess would be an index out of bound, i.e., a position that surpasses the size of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `check_board` is declared as an array of *pointers* when it *should* be an array of `struct`. Likewise for `dummy` and `dummy_symbol` (which you don't even need, by the way).

If you want to `malloc` a symbol, then `malloc` a symbol, not a pointer to a symbol.  But you don't even need to `malloc` those: just declare stack-based variables:

```
struct Player_symbols player_1_symbols; // no pointer, no malloc needed
```

Comment: Could you suggest how to declare array of struct for checker_board?

Comment: To declare an array of `struct`, just take the `*` out.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this slight change in your code.
As you are using structure then allocate memory dynamically to the structure instead of pointer to the variable.

```
struct Checker_piece* checker_board[boardheight][boardwidth];



 struct Checker_piece* dummy;
    struct Player_symbols* dummy_symbol;

    player_1_pieces = (Checker_piece *)malloc(12*sizeof(Checker_piece));
    player_2_pieces = (Checker_piece *)malloc(12*sizeof(Checker_piece));
    struct Player_symbols *player_1_symbols,*player_2_symbols;

    player_1_symbols = (Player_symbols *)malloc(sizeof(Player_symbols));
    player_2_symbols = (Player_symbols *)malloc(sizeof(Player_symbols));
```

PS-You don't need to type cast malloc if you are programmimg in C.